# In TFS 2017 can you execute all phases on the same agent?

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines

We're using TFS 2017 Update 3 on premise for CI and CD. Our build server has two agents. We only have a few automated releases at the moment but are working on adding more.  A typical release has 3 environments and each environment has X phases for the sake of logically separating/grouping activities.  For example:

- Phase 1 - Replace tokens (downloads the artifacts and replaces tokens)
- Phase 2 - Deploy a database (skips artifact download, uses output from Phase 1, and deploys the db)
- Phase 3 - Deploy a service (skips artifact download, uses output from Phase 1,  and deploys a service)

Up until recently, because we only have few releases, only one release happened at a time and it's worked fine.  Tonight I got bit.

What happened was Release 1 started and when it was in Phase 3, Release 2 was queued.  Release 2 started Phase 1 on Agent 2 because Agent 1 was being used by Release 1.  When Release 2 got to Phase 2, Agent 1 was now free so it performed Phases 2 & 3 on Agent 1.  This lead to Phases 2 & 3 of Release 2 operating out of the folder where the release for the previous environment ran thereby resulting in the wrong settings being copied to the target environment. I hope that's clear.  Essentially QA settings were copied to PROD.

I had figured that all Phases of an Environment started and finished on the same agent.

So, to achieve "Agent Affinity", is my only option to use 1 Phase?  I'll miss the logical separation of steps.  I don't see anywhere I can control that.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phases should not depend on the output of previous phases. Use a single phase.

You can use task groups to logically group steps together.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It makes sense and I guess I learned that the hard way.  I had considered Task Groups but they seem better for generic reusable tasks whereas what I'm doing, while having similarities with other releases, tends to be more specific.  I also didn't like that they were managed outside the release (but I get why they are).  I really just wanted a way to visually separate/group items.  Maybe they have that in TFS 2018.  Thanks again.